# Upload multipart file with nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, upload, multipart

I am trying to upload files through my web application, but i am keep getting 404 on uploads.

I am useing Nginx as a reverse proxy for .net core web application. Everything worked fine so far, however upload of files for some reason fails.

I am new to nginx, so i might just miss a simple config for this to work.

When i am uploading i am sending post request with content type :

> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryOge8Ovx1kqih4lfp

Nginx config :

```
  server {
     proxy_request_buffering off;

listen 80;
location / {

proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
client_max_body_size 500m;

}
}
```

I really cant figure out where to look for an error

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check the user permission of /var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body

Comment: Check error.log. If permission is the problem, it should be mentioned there. Nginx saves temporary file in nginx/tmp/client_body. user of nginx needs permission to it. If you run nginx for the first time by user nginx and later change it to someone else, he may not have enough permissions.